# Number the nodes at the end of nested <xsl:for-each>

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT transformation with several nested `<xsl:for-each>` and `<xsl:apply-templates>`.

Now i need to number the nodes at the end of this for-each and apply-templates. Everything I tried just numbered the iterations on an level of for-each (e.q. 1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4 but I need 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

(*I'm pretty inexperienced with XSLT, but attempted to solve this problem with different variants of `<xsl:number>` and `position()`.*)

test.xml

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C/>
        <C/>
        <C/>
        <C/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C/>
        <C/>
    </B>
</A>
```

text.xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="A">
    <xsl:for-each select="B">
        <xsl:for-each select="C">
            <xsl:number/>,
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

test.out

```
1,2,3,4,1,2,
```

I would like to have

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

**EDIT**: This example is to simple, it works with `<xsl:number level="any" />`. I first have to make a better example

Comment: Got any XML/XSL samples for us to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="A/B/C">
  <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
</xsl:template>
```

`position()` always returns the position of the current node in the batch of nodes that is being processed at the moment. Your solution:

```
<xsl:template match="A">
  <xsl:for-each select="B">
    <xsl:for-each select="C">
      <xsl:number/>,
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Processes four batches of nodes:

- One batch of `<A>` nodes. They go from position 1 to 1.
- One batch of `<B>` nodes. They go from position 1 to 2.
- Two Batches of `<C>` nodes. They go from position 1-4 and 1-2

While my solution processes, by selecting them directly:

- One batch of `<C>` nodes. They go from position 1-6

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:number value="count(preceding::C) + 1"/><xsl:if test="following::C">,</xsl:if>
```

(or something similar) should do it.

Comment: +1 Very nice ... only the commas are missing - how would i test for the very last C element?

Comment: Added conditional comma above

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the variable:

```
<xsl:template match="A">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="1"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="B">
        <xsl:for-each select="C">
            <xsl:variable name="count" select="$count + 1"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="count" />,
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This results in an error: "The variable or parameter 'count' was duplicated within the same scope."

Comment: @antyrat: There is no such thing as "incrementing a variable" in XSLT. All variables are constant, you can never change their values.